# How to get the creation date of a contact?

Tags: ios, cncontact

Using the new [Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328) in iOS 9, how can I get the contacts' creation date?

In previous versions, by using the Address Book Framework, I could do this:

```
ABRecordRef person = ...
NSDate *creationDate = (__bridge_transfer NSDate *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonCreationDateProperty);
```

but I couldn't find the right way to do it using the new framework, there is no obvious property in `CNContact` nor any relevant key.

Disclaimer: this question was [originally posted to SO.es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/289/270), but as it didn't get any answer, I decided to post it here too.

Comment: Please file a bug report with Apple. The Contacts Framework did a very incompetent job of taking over from the Address Book Framework, and this is just one more example.

Comment: @matt Ok, reported in issue #23744176. I'm not expecting much attention from Apple though...

Comment: Every little bit helps! Even if you get closed as a duplicate, it's meaningful.

Comment: I was just checking new Contacts framework for same thing, really how could they omit such a basic thing?